# Unable to add multiple rows using WHILE statement in servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am making an online e-portal site for my project using jsps and servlet using jdbc.However I am getting a strange error.I am unable to add multiples rows using the while statement.I am getting the **Product ID(PID)** of all the items available **in a cart from a hashmap**  via session.and I store corresponding keys i.e **(keys are pids here and values are quantities)**.I am getting pids and getting the corresponding attributes of that product using that pid.and I am updating the particular user table with items in his/her cart in a **while** loop.using an insertuserdata.First I am checking if a table exists for a particular user..then **I am just adding the records else I am creating a new table and inserting records one by one** 
Here is the servlet code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            HttpSession ses=request.getSession();
            HashMap h=(HashMap)ses.getAttribute("list");
            String usr=(String) ses.getAttribute("usr");
            String usertable="USER"+usr;
            Collection c=h.keySet();
            Iterator itr=c.iterator();
            connect.dbconnect con=new connect.dbconnect();
            int tCost=Integer.parseInt((String)ses.getAttribute("tCost"));
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                Object pid=itr.next();
                String v;
                v=con.Pid_buy((String)pid);
                String pname=v;
                String quan=(String)h.get(pid);
                Date dt=new java.util.Date();
                String date=(dt.toString());
                String status="Purchased";

               try{
                    if(con.chktable(usertable))
                {
                   int num=con.getSID(usertable);
                   con.insertuserdata(usertable,num+1,quan,date,pname,status,tCost);
                }
                if(!con.chktable(usertable))
                {
                    con.createnewuser(usertable);
                    con.insertuserdata(usertable,1,quan,date,pname,status,tCost);
                }
               }catch(Exception e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               con.updateStock((String)pid,Integer.parseInt(quan));
            }
               h.clear();
               String count=null;
               ses.setAttribute("count", count);
               ses.setAttribute("list", h);
              // response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");


        } finally {  


            out.close();
        }
    }
```

here list is the hashmap containing the list of items and their quantity.tCost is just a total cost I am getting as parametre.
**getSID** function gives me the number of rows in the table.
**PID_BUY** gives me the name of the product

Here the problem is that its only adding the last product in the database and not all the products.and I am getting a **GENERAL error**

following is my **Insertuserdata** method

```
public void insertuserdata(String tbname,int pk,String quantity,String date,String pname,String status,float tCost) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:product");
              // Table exists
            String data=tbname ;

            PreparedStatement smt1=con.prepareStatement("insert into ["+data+"] values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            smt1.setInt(1,pk);
            smt1.setString(2,quantity);
            smt1.setString(3,date);
            smt1.setString(4,pname);
            smt1.setString(5,status);
            smt1.setFloat(6,tCost);
            smt1.executeUpdate();




        }
```

Comment: try using struts and hibernate or integrating spring for secure applications